# Style of a entries in Longman dictionary?

Tags: dictionaries

I can not delineate the difference between **formal, literary, and written** styles of a verb in Longman dictionary. please look at the below picture.Note that the entries are four different words
[image]

Comment: It's not clear what your question is here.

Comment: I think picture can say what I mean.

Comment: Please do **not** use a picture, especially a picture of text, as an integral part of your question. Type out the text you are confused about.

Comment: @ randomhead I mostly confused about entries that the "written" in purple has written in front of them. what does it mean?

Comment: @Arash, I have the full use of my eyes and can see the image and your circled annotations perfectly fine; I was not confused about what your question was. But not everyone can. Posting an image and saying "what does the circled word mean" is of no use to a blind person who uses a screen reader—and perhaps that blind person could have answered your question. I meant that you should type out, in your question (use the [edit link!](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/290567/edit)), what *exactly* you are confused about.

Comment: In any case providing a link to the source text you are confused about (in this case, it appears to be the part of a dictionary that describes the style guidelines used in that dictionary) is helpful for additional context.

Comment: I've gone to the Longman website and nowhere could I find any explanation of their definitions. So I have no idea why they class **do something** as **formal**. I use that phrase spoken and informally all the time. You may want to find a different dictionary.

Comment: Did you look up the words "written" and "literary"?

Comment: @gotube The entries are four different words and Longman dictionary categorize them as informal, literary, written, or even informal and the question here  is what does it mean to say your entry fall into the written group

Comment: @FeliniusRex It may be a misleading screenshot.  Perhaps "do something" is the approximate definition, and the word being defined as "formal" is "execute", for example.

Comment: @rjpond Go to the Longman's dictionary website, like I did, and you will see the same style used for their entries. They don't explain what their terminology means. That's why I recommended a different dictionary.

Comment: Thank you for all your help.

Comment: I can see that it is indeed the "do something" sense of the word "execute" that is being labelled "formal", not the expression "do something" - https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/execute

Comment: @rjpond I've mentioned that this picture is for four different entries which I've cropped the relevant part of every entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**written**: unlikely to appear in spoken English, but could appear in any kind of written English.

**literary**: appears only in novels or poems, where the writer is aiming to create an impression beyond the simple meaning of the words. There are many ways of doing this: there is a whole [web site](https://literarydevices.net/) listing the possibilities.

**formal**: appears only in formal documents: academic publications, official reports, business letters, legal documents, etc.

Comment: This is the thing I was looking for. Thanks a bunch.